# Android - Comparing String Input On A Textfile Content

Tags: android, database, text-files, notepad

May I ask you to guide me how I can accomplish this problem?
I need to compare an inputWord to a string inside a .txt file and if found, return the whole line but if not, show "word not found".

Example:

```
inputWord: abacus

Text file content:
abaca - n. large herbaceous Asian plant of the banana family.
aback - adv. archaic towards or situated to the rear.
abacus - n. a frame with rows of wires or grooves along which beads are slid, used for calculating.
...
so on

Returns: abacus with its definition
```

What i am trying to do is compare my inputWord to the words before the " - " (hyphen as delimiter), if they dont match, move to the next line. If they match, copy the whole line.

I hope it doesnt seem like im asking you to "do my homework" but I tried tutorials around different forums and sites. I also read java docs but i really cannot put them together to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:

Here's my current code:

```
if(enhancedStem.startsWith("a"))
                {
                    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.definitiona); 
                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        String s = in.readLine();
                        String delimiter = " - ";
                        String del[];
                        while(s != null)
                        {
                            s = in.readLine();
                            del = s.split(delimiter);
                            if (enhancedStem.equals(del[0]))
                            {
                                in.close();
                                databaseOutput.setText(s);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        in.close();
                        }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        databaseOutput.setText("" + e);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e1) {
                        databaseOutput.setText("" + e1);
                    }
                }
```

Thanks a lot! Here's what I came up, and it returns the definition of inputs properly but the problem is, when i enter a word not found in the textfile, the app crashes. The catch phrase doesn't seem to work. Have any idea how I can trap it? Logcat says  NullPointerExcepetion at line 4342 which is

```
s = in.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the format of each line in the text file is uniform. This could be done in the following manner :

1) Read the file line by line.

2) Split each line based on the delimiter and collect the split String tokens in a temp String array.

3) The first entry in the temp token array will be the word before the "-" sign.

4) Compare the first entry in the temp array with the search string and return the entire line if there is a match.

Following code could be put up in a function to accomplish this :

```
String delimiter = "-";
String[] temp;
String searchString = "abacus";

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

while (in.readLine() != null) {
    String s = in.readLine();

    temp = s.split(delimiter);

    if(searchString.equals(temp[0])) {
        in.close();
        return s;
    }
}

in.close();
return ("Word not found");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the response. I will try to this code as soon as I get home! :)

Comment: I got an error that says: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <my path>: open failed: ENOENT (no such file or directory)

I tried putting these in place of "file":
"C:\\workspace\\raw\\definitiona.txt\\"
and
"\\res\\raw\\definitiona.txt"

but both says not found.

Comment: Try removing the extra \\ at the end from the "C:\\workspace\\raw\\definitiona.txt\\". Should work.

Comment: Hi! I tried the code you gave and worked perfectly! I just used an InputStreamReader instead of FileReader. But I encounter a crash I cannot trap. Can you check it up? I made an update. Thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: what does the crash look like ? What does the logcat say when the crash happens ?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
__java.lang.NullPointerException
__at com.atienzaerni.thesis.secondactivity$2.onEditorAction(secondactivity.java:4318).

4318 varies. sometimes it gives other  line. And it seems that when i use "-" as delimiter, it crashes but " - " works fine.

Comment: I believe your input file has spacing after and before the delimiter like " - " and hence when just "-" is used the tokens do not get generated as expected and so the comparison in the equals method results in NullPointerException. Also the error showing up on different lines indicates that the formatting might not be uniform across the whole file.So better use " - " if it works well.

Answer (score 0):

you may try like:

```
myreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String text = "MyInput Word";

while(!((text.equals(reader.readLine())).equals("0")));
```

Comment: I've been having problems with the path of the filereader. it cannot find my directory even if i input the exact path of my text file. :(